# Nextag ROI optimizer code for woo commerce. How do I remove the # sign from my order number?

Tags: woocommerce, roi, optimization

Hi I am trying to install the Nextag ROI optimizer code from Nextag into my woocommerce theme/plugin. (thankyou.php template) It is working except I cannot get rid of the # symbol in the final output. The Nextag stats will not show my order numbers if a # sign is included. (At least this is my working theory since my order numbers will not populate.)

So it returns a #1234 instead of 1234 when reporting.  How can I get rid of this so I can get proper reporting. The one variable or function in questions is "var order"

Once this question is answered I believe I can also do this for all the other PPC engines that have free trackers as well and you will be help many more in the future.

I'm sorry if my lingo is lacking as I am not a programmer of any kind.

Please note it is working when I view source code, its just I need to get rid of the # in my order number.

Thank you for your time.

```
   <!--
    /* NexTag ROI Optimizer Data */
    var id = 'hidden';
    var rev = '<?php echo $order->order_total; ?>';
    var order = '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>';
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://imgsrv.nextag.com/imagefiles/includes/roitrack.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The guys at woothemes helped me out.  So to make the Nextag ROI optimizer work with woocommerce you need to go to the thankyou.php and add this code right below `<p><?php _e('Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce'); ?></p>` Make sure ####### is your unique merchant ID with nextag.

If you do not know how to change the thank you php you can use notepad.exe stock with windows or open it with a free editor called notepad++ which is what I used.  Then you can overwrite the old thankyou.php OR copy the PHP to the area that allow you to protect changes.(outside of the scope of this answer)   You should know that if the woocommerce plugin is updated you will have to reload the code back into thankyou.php.

Your snippet is below have fun.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    /* NexTag ROI Optimizer Data */
    var id = '#######';
    var rev = '<?php echo $order->order_total; ?>';
    var order = '<?php echo $order->id; ?>';
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://imgsrv.nextag.com/imagefiles/includes/roitrack.js"></script>
```

It should also be said that this code can be enhanced further to contain other product data.  So if know know those pieces and can really trick this code out.  Post it!